# Video background not rendering in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox, video, background, background-image

I created this webpage (http://www.lovehatecreate.net/Java%20Brewin/index%202.html) and used a video as a background image by using jQuery and fitvids.js

It works in every browser except Firefox. I am somewhat of a beginner, so I have no idea how to tackle this. Any advice on how to fix would be great!

Thank you!

P.S. This is just a SAMPLE, that is why I am using watermarked video and images. I do not claim ownership of the video or images on this site, they belong to their respective authors and can be purchased on fotolia.com.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues. The first problem is <strike>a lot</strike> most of your CSS and JavaScript resources are sending 403 Forbidden HTTP headers, which means that your server is denying access to those files. You can fix the file permissions in your server settings, to allow these resources to be accessed by the public.

I also get a JavaScript error:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

which will usually mess up other JavaScript on the page. And upon investigation:

[image]

I see strange A characters. I only see these characters in a certain part of your code, which leads me to believe that this is a character encoding issue that arose from copying and pasting code from a certain editor that encoded differently than UTF-8.

**Edit:**

You won't be able to see that the characters are different in certain editors. The only time you will notice is if the characters are incorrectly interpreted by a code editor (or browser). Some editors have a [byte-level search and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188695/any-way-to-detect-and-remove-or-fix-bad-characters-resulting-from-bad-encoding#answer-5202636). I would recommend you use a Unicode text editor, and save your code and then re-open it, so that you can see character issues. You have some `=` symbols in your URL that are not in Unicode and are throwing errors. Also, you need to represent your `&` characters with HTML entities (`&amp;`)

If you find character encoding for the web confusing, [here's a good read](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-web-character-encoding/).

Comment: You are correct I did change editors in the middle of coding the site. Let me go and try to fix my server etc... actually it's very late if I do it now I'll mess things up. Thank you for your help I'll fix stuff and be back tomorrow.

Comment: Alex, I am viewing the code in cPanel's html editor and the strange a characters aren't coming up...? Can you guide me on how to fix this? I used a handy Google Maps extension for Dreamweaver. Could this have caused this? I am on CS6. Thanks.

Comment: I also changed permissions. Let me know if that helped matters.

Comment: @JulieS I'm still getting 403 forbidden on, for instance, http://www.lovehatecreate.net/Java%20Brewin/example/css/website.css. I added an update to my answer. You will need to either find a text editor that can do UTF-8/Unicode conversion, or completely re-type your code in a UTF-8 editor and save as UTF-8, then copy and paste. Also, the permissions issues could have something to do with your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I found the issue with the index 2.html file and the UTF, and got it fixed. Works on my end with no strange characters, let me know how it works for you. I have a help desk person from my web host helping me fix the 403 Forbidden issue right now : http://www.lovehatecreate.net/Java%20Brewin/index%202.html

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I am beyond grateful.

Comment: Alex, after working with my provider and I have fixed all issues including permissions. Let me know if everything works right on your end. Then if you could advise me on how to best get the video to work that would be great. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @JulieS There's lots of 404 not found HTTP messages, so make sure the paths to your files are correct. and you have an extra `</script>` tag which shows up in red on FireFox if you right click and choose "View Page Source".

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I fixed other errors, and then found an .htaccess fix for the video.

Comment: @JulieS Looks fixed on my Firefox now as well!